# Shop opening hours in Russia

Tags: russia, moscow, saint-petersburg

How are opening hours in tourist areas, sport clubs, malls, etc. in Moscow and St Petersburg?

Is it like Europe that in the evening (like 7 PM) there are almost no open malls or clubs?

Comment: This may be different between 2 cities.  Moscow has shops open to 2-3 am due to traffic.

Comment: It's wild. I have had full on surf 'n turf in Moscow at 3 AM.  GUM is open until 10 PM 7 days a week and other shops in the Kremlin area can be open 24/7.  Peter is a bit more conservative where shopping hours are concerned, but the clubbing is nonstop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Saint Petersburg (as in many big Russian cities) **malls** (*торгово-развлекательный центр* or *гипермаркет*) mostly work from `10:00` till `22:00`. Also (if you need some basic foodstuff) there are many `24/7` **food supermarkets** (*супермаркет*, *продукты*) in Russia like Перекресток, Пятерочка, Лента, Азбука вкуса, Карусель, Полушка, etc. Such supermarkets accept Visa & MasterCard by the way.

There are many **sport clubs** (*спортивный клуб*, *фитнес-центр*) which work from `7:00` till `23:00`, but not all. It seems there are only 3 **waterparks** (*аквапарк*) in St. Petersburg, and they work about from `10:00` till `22:30`.

Work schedules of **banks** (*банк*) are very variable. You need to check it yourself for accuracy. By the way there are too many `24/7` **ATM points** (*банкомат*) which may be placed in common places or be accessible even if the its bank office is closed.

**Museums** (*музей*) work generally from `10:00`, but while there are may be very long turns, you should borrow your place beforehand. For example, **The State Hermitage** (Эрмитаж) works mainly from `10:30` till `18:00` except Mondays when it's closed. **The Russian Museum** (Русский музей) works mainly from `10:00` till `18:00` except Tuesdays. And so on.

St. Petersburg **subway** stations (*метро*) are opened to entrance about from `5:30` till `0:30`, but there is own schedule for each station.

You may find many firms and check its work times at http://2gis.ru (in Russian only, but they have offline mobile and PC apps also).

Answer (score 10):

Medium-sized food chain shops are open from `10:00` till `22:00`. Smaller shops are often `24H`. **Malls** close as early as `20:00` (and might open later).

Note that in Russia, you can't buy booze after `21:00 ~ 23:00` (varies per region) even if shop is open. Sometimes you can buy something unofficially (don't count on this, especially in Moscow).

In **Theatres**, performance usually starts at `19:00`.

If we're talking **music clubs**, live performance usually start at `20:00`, often delayed, and ends before midnight. If we're talking about **nightclubs**, as their name implies, they work even later.

Many **restaurants** open at noon and close around midnight or an hour earlier; in order to staff & visitors get home via subway without problems. Some are open `24H`.

**Museums** often close at `19:00` and stop accepting new visitors at `18:00`. No idea about sport clubs, I guess some might run all night.

Note that in Russia, **banks** behave like most **commercial shops**: Many close at `20:00`, work on saturdays and some even open on sundays (usually with shortened work hours).

Don't expect to find many cafes open before ten in the morning.

In smaller cities or on outskirts this may vary, usually towards shorter work times.

Comment: Malls close not on `20:00`, `22:00` is more likely.

Comment: What about sport clubs? eg waterparks, bungee clubs, etc.

Comment: @ReZa My sports club is open untill 23:00, far from Moscow and no traffic issues. It's just a normal thing here. Aquaparks are open till 22:00. Half of grocery stores are open 24/7. Small shops open untill 21:00, shoes repair till 19:00. Swimming pool next to me allows you enter till 20:30, works till 21:45. Bungee clubs? If you mean sports centers with alpinism, they work till ~21. If you mean outdoor, those usually close earlier.